# what triggers gcc -fsplit-stack option to allocate another stack segment

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation, stack-overflow, processor

I'm trying to make sense of how this option works.

In the source code of g++, it only says a segment of stack is allocated when a processor specific function is called.

I'm wondering which processor function will trigger it.

For reference, here is the source code of this option,

https://sourceware.org/svn/gcc/tags/gcc_7_3_0_release/libgcc/generic-morestack.c